# Apps Script: How to selectively apply split to an array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For the following Google Apps Script function, the `External IDs` column has the value `[object Object]` appearing for all rows. How to fix the issue so that I get the column values like the following?

`Expected Result`

```
| Track ID | Name  | Album  | Added At | External IDs       |
|----------|-------|--------|----------|--------------------|
| ABC      | Song1 | Album1 | today1   | {isrc=123,ean=456} |
| DEF      | Song2 | Album2 | today2   | {isrc=123}         |
| XYZ      | Song3 | Album3 | today3   | {isrc=123,upc=789} |
```

```
function func() {

  var data = [
    { "track": { "name": "Song1", "album": {"name":"Album1"}, "id": "ABC", "url": "www.example.com/1", "external_ids":{"isrc":"123","ean":"456"} }, "added_at":"today1" },
    { "track": { "name": "Song2", "album": {"name":"Album2"}, "id": "DEF", "url": "www.example.com/2", "external_ids":{"isrc":"123"} }, "added_at":"today2" },
    { "track": { "name": "Song3", "album": {"name":"Album3"}, "id": "XYZ", "url": "www.example.com/3", "external_ids":{"isrc":"123","upc":"789"} }, "added_at":"today3" }
  ];

  var headers = [["Track ID", "Name", "Album", "Added At","External IDs"]];
  var keys = ["track.id", "track.name", "track.album.name", "added_at", "track.external_ids"];

  var richTextValues = data.map((data) =>
    keys.map(c => {
      // var keys = c.split('.');
      var keys = (c !== 'track.external_ids') ? c.split('.') : ["track","external_ids"];
      var value = keys.reduce((a, b) => a[b], data);
      var rt = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value);
      if (keys[0] === "track" && keys[1] === "id") rt.setLinkUrl(data.track.url);
      return rt.build();
    })
  );

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Set headers
  sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers[0].length).setValues(headers);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, richTextValues.length, richTextValues[0].length).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected result using your showing script and samlpe value and your showing table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tanaike. I have updated the question with the expected result. I only want to fix the `external_ids` column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your expected result, you want to directly show `{isrc=123,ean=456}` to the cell. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, I need to see it exactly that way.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to directly show `{isrc=123,ean=456}` to the cell.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var rt = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value);
```

#### To:

```
var rt = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(typeof value == "object" ? JSON.stringify(value) : value);
```

#### Note:

- If you want `{isrc=123,ean=456}` instead of `{"isrc":"123","ean":"456"}`, please modify as follows.

  ```
    var rt = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(typeof value == "object" ? JSON.stringify(value).replace(":", "=").replace(/"/g, "") : value);
  ```
- In this modification, the object is converted to the string type.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this works. Also, is replacing the string the best option here?

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. About `Also, is replacing the string the best option here?`, if you want `{isrc=123,ean=456}`, I thought that `replace(":", "=").replace(/"/g, "")` might be useful. Of course, the value `{isrc=123,ean=456}` can be directly created from the object. I think that you can choose one of them. By the way, I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for helping and teaching me along the way. You have a great day!

Comment: @Shantanu Thank you for replying. As additional information, for example, if you want to know the method for directly creating `{isrc=123,ean=456}` from the object, I think that please modify to ``var rt = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(typeof value == "object" ? `{${Object.entries(value).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`).join(",")}}` : value);``.